# How to display first character in drop down list

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I would like to display only the first characters in the drop down list.

For example,
I have names like Adam,Harry,James in mysql table. I've created a dropdown list showing the names Adam,Harry etc. But, I want to display only their first characters like A,H,J etc. in the drop down list. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use MySQL [LEFT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) :-

```
LEFT(names , 1)
```

query like that :-

```
select LEFT(names , 1) from table
```

Comment: It didn't work bro :| check the code below
$sql = "SELECT LEFT(name,1) FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='name'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

Comment: $sql = "SELECT LEFT(name,1) as name FROM table";

Comment: use this query @HulkSmash

Comment: now i want to display the names that start with the character selected from drop down. For example, in the dropdown we have A,B,C etc characters. Now if i select B and click on submit, I should be able to get all the names that start with B, is there any way to go that? I think i shud use get parameter? @Rahautos

Comment: $sql = "SELECT LEFT(name,1) as name,name as fullname FROM table";

Comment: Use. $row['fullname']

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I hope this will help.

```
<option value='" . $row['name'] ."'>" . substr($row['name'], 0, 1) ."</option>
```